# Low cost swarm positioning

Tags: microcontroller, radio, high-frequency, pcb-antenna

I'm looking for a way to make a swarm of sensors know their position using low cost, low power system (ie ESP32.)

Requirement:

- low cost per device
- low power use on devices
- 1m accuracy is enough
- 2D only
- 1 position every 5 sec is enough
- 500x500m area
- only the device has to know its position
- there is a permanent one way data broadcast connection to the devices that we can use (no ways for the device to communicate with the server)
- the setup on the field like installing beacons and control system could be expensive (only the devices must be cheap and low power)

Time of flight on devices seems too power hungry and expensive to me. Computing offset like GPS does also.

I thought about a solution:
 - Using three beacons on the corners.
 - The server send a message saying "next time you get a positioning signal it means you're on row 1". 
- It wait a bit to be sure all devices get the information. 
 - Then ask the controler to send a message from a pair of beacons with just the right time offset so their signals meet on row 1.
 - All devices that are on row 1 get signal from both beacons at the same time.
 - They now know they are on row 1.
 - The process is repeated for each row.
 - Then for each column using another pair of beacons.

This approach does not require time of flight chip nor guessing the offset on the device side. Just detecting a match between two pulses. It's quite easy to make a AND logic door (a transistor) between two antennas for two different frequencies.

I'm not sure the signal will meet along straight lines, more like hyperbolic curves, some math will convert to x and y. 
We can sync the beacons with one master antenna. There could also be  master antennas on each rows and columns. So there's no need to mesure time offset.

Do you think this is a good approach? If you have some links that would help me. I'm wondering how to precisely control the offset between emitted signals.

Edit : I changed explanation to make it more clear as comment requested.

Comment: These kinds of things are fundamentally challenging with few compromise-free solutions.  What you are seeking is within the capability of *differential* GPS or a comparable (if challenging to build) custom system.

Comment: This approach sounds more plausible than the usual attempts. How did your last attempt work out?

Comment: If you can tell whether two pulses are synced, you can probably extract the time difference between two pulses. Sounds conceptually similar to [Loran-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loran-C)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have not done any prototype yet, I'm a software developer, I know nothing about radio frequencies, I learnt yesterday how antennas work :)

Comment: So you want to shift the individual transmission times of each beacon so the waves arrive simultaneously on particular areas of the field? How did you plan on synchronizing the time reference for said beacons? That seems like one of the more difficult problems to me.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have really no idea, but you are going to help me ! ;-) The beacons could wired to a server system. The system could be calibrated once. There is no price limit for the beacons system, only for the devices.

Comment: @bokan Well, if you say *no* price limit, you could always launch more precise clocks than GPS into orbit and just use that....

Comment: @Hearth no it will require offset computing on devices :) I mean it could cost a one million dollars or more and the project will still be interesting, but unfortunately I could not afford financing it :-(

Comment: A simple server isn't going to work because your signals travel at the speed of light but the signal coming from the server also travels at about the speed of light. It's like me sending a messenger on horseback with a note that has the the time my clock reading at so you can set your clock to match it when he arrives. By the time the time sync information arrives, it is out of date by enough that it is useless for the system you are using it in.

Comment: Unless you plan to account for the propagation time of signals from the server to each beacon, but if you only do it once then you need atomic clocks so the signal continues to stay synchronized when the beacons are keep track of time on their own. And if you do time syncs every time you send, your beacons still need an accurate clock though I don't have a good feel for how accurate it would actually need to be.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for your interest. There's no need for accurate sync between servers and devices. Server broadcast "next time you get a positioning signal means you are on row 1" -pause - then ask the controler to send pulses on two beacons with the right amount of offset so they meet on row 1, then do same for other rows and each device will know which row they are. Repeat for columns with a different pair of beacons.

Comment: @bokan You still seem to be missing the fact that the messages you send to the beacons take about as much time to travel to the beacon and the signal the beacon sends to the swarm unless your server is exactly the same distance from all the beacons or unless you send an individual message to each beacon and account for the distance between server and each beacon so the messages arrives at each beacon at exactly the same time.

Comment: @DKNguyen, no, I said there is a - pause - between. Also the positioning signal can be sent several times to be devices get it.

Comment: If both you and I leave our houses driving to the same place, at the same speed and want to meet up at exactly the same time, the person who is closer to the destination needs to know in advance when the person who is farther is going to leave so they know how long to wait before leaving. The farther person can't drive over to the closer person's house to tell them they are leaving now, then drive all the way back home so that they can leave because the message about when they were leaving is wrong since the speed at which the synchronization traveled is the same speed as the travelers.

Comment: But this seems to be exactly what you want to do when you want your server or controller to command two beacons to send a message carefully spaced out in time without noting how far the beacons are from the server or controller because the server/controller message takes a different time to reach each beacon.

Comment: @DKNguyen I changed the question again to make it more clear.

Comment: @DKNguyen the system will be carefully setup. We can tell the controler how far are the beacons. It can also be calibrated after being setup. A special device that can be used to comunicate with the server. The server tries various parameters and a user with a receiver go on the field and register where it really is.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea. You mention an esp32, and it being a widely used wifi networked device works in your favor.

I think you have a couple of challenges in the project. First is that all devices in the swarm have to be operating in a precisely synchronized manner. I've come across White Rabbit project that make use of a very precise clock synchronization protocol across multiple devices on a network. Using this type of protocol would allow the swarm devices to operate in the same time frame. With some equipment you can easily cover the area specified with a single wifi network all swarm devices have to be connected to. I haven't looked at implementing the protocol on a microcontroller, but it should work in principle.

Second challenge is generating an event, or series of events, detectable by all swarm devices in the specified area, and applying triangulation principles based on the time difference measured by each device in the swarm from the moment of event triggering. 500x500 meter distance isn't too large for an audible frequency sound to travel (single-tone whistles can be detected from kilometers away). Having a small microphone listening to the specific tone triggering an interrupt to time stamp an event is all that would need to be done. The base station setup would perform self-calibration from the triggered events to account for the effect on sound speed by temperature and pressure. To get 1m accuracy you would need to be able to detect an event with a precision of under 3 ms, which is achievable on the esp32.

Comment: Funny you said I have an interesting idea then describe the exact opposite of what I meant! The solution I suggest does not require syncing the swarm nor time of flight detection. Each device just detect when it gets two signal at the same time and the data channel tells it that it is a this position.

Comment: @bokan And how do you plan to transmit both signals at the same time? You are overlooking the synching required by your transmitters. Your swarm might not need to be synced, but your beacons do. It's probably just as much trouble either way.

Comment: @DKNguyen maybe we can sync the two beacons by triggering them with a third one being between the them. Using another frequency.

Comment: @Bokan The "master" beacon would need to be precisely equidistant from all the other beacons that actually transmit the pulse to the swarm which is probably easier to do than trying to make some other time reference. I don't think it would be reliable for the master to also communicate with the swarm because it would need to know the distance to the slave beacons so it knows how long to wait after sending the synch signal before sending a signal to the swarm. You can try it, but it would basically required a clock fast enough and accurate enough for time-of-flight.

Comment: @Dmitri 1m is 3us (microsecond) accuracy which I don't think we ça mesure with ESP32

Comment: It's as DKNguyen said, precise measurement will have to done somewhere. I've read the other answer thread and your edited post, and you seem to be going off an idea that only seems easier at first glance. For example, you say it will be easy to set up your 3 transmitted at known distances to reach other with a single trigger beacon equidistant between them, but precise physical measurements over hundreds of meters are not done easily by laypeople and require specialized surveying equipment and staff.

Comment: In addition, circuitry to detect two RF pulses with enough precision to know within 1 meter error when they arrived relative to each other is more complex than you think, even if all you want to know is if they are "close enough" and not the exact time between arrival

Comment: I've done a quick search online and multiple people get ESP32 interrupt latency in hundreds of nanoseconds ranges, ten times what you'll need to reliably register an audio event with enough accuracy.

Comment: @Dmitri s :  my system does not requires any timing on the devices. They just require a circuit that rise a i/o pin when they get two pulses simultaneously on two different frequencies. Please read the question again as I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: @bokan : I understand what you are getting at, but there is no such thing as simultaneous in electronics - there are propagation delays in everything from the simplest antenna to internal wiring of an IC chip. On top of that, any firmware will take time to execute even the simplest instruction, and it may not even be an exact amount of time depending on a chip (it costs extra to have accurate timing). The reason I suggest acoustic signal is because it propagates relatively slowly in air, and electronics will not need to be very advanced to detect difference between acoustic signals.